# Sending multiple arguments to pthread_create()

Tags: c, linux, multithreading

This is a program from The Linux Programming Interface (original code [here](http://man7.org/tlpi/code/online/book/threads/thread_incr.c.html)). What I am trying to do is to send 2 "arguments" to threadFunc using [pthread_create()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html) for the goals listed below:

1. First one serves as an iterator in the for loop in threadFunc();
2. Second one identifies the thread that is currently doing work in threadFunc(). So it will be some sort of printable ID for the thread.

To achieve these goals I create this struct that contains 2 member variables:

```
struct arguments {
    int loops;
    pthread_t self;
};
```

And this function loops 'threadFuncLoops' times incrementing global variable 'glob'

```
static void * threadFunc(void *arg)
{
    struct arguments * threadFuncArgs = arg;
    int threadFuncLoops = *(arg.loops);

    for (int j = 0; j < threadFuncLoops; j++) {

        // Something happens to glob
    }

    return NULL;
}
```

In main() I am creating 2 threads (t1, t2) and send them to threadFunc():

```
    struct arguments newArguments;

    s = pthread_create(&t1, NULL, threadFunc, &newArguments);

    s = pthread_create(&t2, NULL, threadFunc, &newArguments);
```

But compiler says in threadFunc()

```
request for member 'loops' in something not a structure or union
```

My questions are:

1. How come "loops" is not in a structure? It is in a struct instance isn't it?
2. How exactly achieve goal #2?

Thank you very much.

Comment: `*(arg.loops);` is incorrect. `loops` is not a pointer so cannot be derferenced. Furthermore, `args` is a `void *` so is not a struct pointer nor a struct. It's wrong on many levels. It should be `threadFuncArgs->loops`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are taking the *address* of `newArguments` in the main function and passing that to your thread function. That means it's no longer a `struct` but a *pointer* to a `struct`, hence you will need to use `->`.

You *could* use the other means of doing `x->y`, which is `(*x).y` and it looks like that may have been what you were trying to achieve with `*(arg.loops)` but there's two problems with that:

- you're trying to dereference `args.loops` which is not a pointer - you should be doing `(*args).loops`; and
- `args` is the wrong type to dereference anyway, you need a pointer to the structure, so it would be `(*threadFuncArgs).loops`.

So, one way to fix this is to use this instead:

```
struct arguments * threadFuncArgs = arg;
int threadFuncLoops = threadFuncArgs->loops;
```

---

One other thing to watch out for. The pointer you pass to the two threads is a pointer to *exactly the same* memory. That means, if one of the threads changes, for example, the `self` field in the structure, it will change for *both.*

Normally, you would fix this in one of (at least) two ways:

- have an array of structures and make sure that each thread gets a unique one, only for itself; or
- have the thread copy its information into local storage, though that will require some re-engineering to ensure the main function doesn't create the second thread until this is done.

Comment: I think you need to type cast: `struct arguments *threadFuncArgs = (struct argument *)arg;`

Comment: @VuongHoang, not in C. Casting to/from `void*` is an implicit operation in that language. C++ not so much but this question is tagged C.

Comment: @VuongHoang: In pure C, you don't _need_ the cast, though it does no harm if you're careful (but can do harm if you're not).  In C++, the cast from `void *` to another pointer type is mandatory.  On Windows systems, it often seems like the compiler people use as a C compiler does require the cast — even though standard C does not.

Comment: ,,or just malloc the struct for each thread, freeing it in the thread function when/if it terminates.

Comment: @paxdiablo now I created 2 structs `newArgument1` and `newArgument2` and send them to `threadFunc()` along with `t1` and `t2` respectively. Do the structs have to be in an array like you said? And to obtain the thread IDs (goal #2), can I do `threadFuncArgs->self=pthread_self();` and then `printf(threadFuncArgs->self);` ?

Comment: @Dylan, no, they don't *have* to be in an array, that's just sometimes easier if you run lots of threads. For two, it's no real issue having independent variables as you've done. In terms of goal 2, `pthread_self()` can be a wide variety of types, suitable only for passing to other `pthread` functions and not *guaranteed* to make sense with `printf`. However, the address you've passed to the thread function is now a unique pointer so it may be more suitable for printing. Or you could load up a small integer into the structure as an ID.

Answer (score 1):

you have to use "->".   Replace arg.loops by threadFuncArgs->loops.